search results webpart with query condition is not showing any results
In sharepoint 2019 I have search page with search box web part and search result webpart. In query condition i try :
{?{searchTerms} path:"https://mytestsharepoint.com/en" urlDepth=2}
to limit the result for EN site only.
If i open search page by server URL http://myserver/en/search.aspx it is working and showing a result.
If i open by public URL https://mytestsharepoint.com/en/search.aspx it is showing : Nothing here matches your search
Also if i used www it is working
https://www.mytestsharepoint.com/en/search.aspx
Any idea why i have to use www in url ?

Whether you configure AAM for the web application?
